# Cannot type into empty TinyMCE 4 area on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, tinymce, tinymce-4

When there is no text in the area, I cannot type in or even focus.
In the official site on the demo of TinyMCE 4, if you delete the whole text and close the virtual keyboard, you cannot get the focus to this area anymore by tapping on it. But there is no such problem if you try this on TinyMCE 3.
Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: I fixed it by adding `html, body {height: 100%;}` in css/tinymce.css

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in TinyMCE 4.0.11

http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=33030